# merge vales in one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to merge all str values for each keys in one dictionary whose len(vlues) are the same. and I expect that user didn't know the len of the dict

```
    dict_old = {
       a: ['a1', 'a2'],
       b: ['b1', 'b2']
    }

    dict_new = {
       c: ['a1_b1', 'a2_b2']
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this is what you want; create a new dictionary where there will be a list that will contain all the pairs of the old dictionary's lists values:

```py
dict_old = {
       'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
       'b': ['b1', 'b2']
    }

dict_new = {'c': ['_'.join(zipped) for zipped in zip(*dict_old.values())]}

print(dict_new)
# {'c': ['a1_b1', 'a2_b2']}
```

Alternatively to unpacking everything using a starred expression you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain): `... in zip(itertools.chain(dict_old.values()))`

Comment: thats what I want! thanks !

Comment: @roy_wang Please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates. Thank you!